# Where does uWSGI define what the envion variable are?

Tags: python, uwsgi

The normal WSGI environ variables are defined [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables), but where are the definitions for the special uWSGI variables such as 'x-wsgiorg.fdevent.readable'?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found where that specific extension's spec is: http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specifications/fdevent.html?highlight=fdevent